# Insert value into vector in a list

Tags: c++, list, vector, c++98

I have a specific list with vectors. i want to add a value to a vector. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
//creating the list with vectors
std::list< vector<string> > adjacencylist;
//adding some vectors to the list...
adjacencylist.push_back(std::vector<std::string>(1, "String"));
adjacencylist.push_back(std::vector<std::string>(1, "String"));
adjacencylist.push_back(std::vector<std::string>(1, "String"));
```

Now I want to add values to the vectors in the list...
I tried for this:

```
std::list< vector<string> >::const_iterator it = adjacencylist.begin();
(*it).push_back("Some more String");
```

I thought that this would work. So I could iterate over all vectors and insert the values that I want. But it does not work. Here the output of the compiler:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
example.cpp:148:31: error: passing ‘const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     (*it).push_back("test");
```

Comment: Try `push_back` instead.

Comment: It is called `push_back`.

Comment: push_back does not work too: `example.cpp:147:50: error: passing ‘const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string<char>]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         (*it).push_back("test");
`

Comment: Use an `iterator`, not a `const_iterator`.

Comment: If one of the questions bellow were useful to you, please remember to mark them as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have declared `it` as a `const_iterator` you have made it such that what `it` references cannot be edited. When you call `push_back` you are attempting to edit the `vector` that `it` points to. You need to replace:

```
std::list< vector<string> >::const_iterator it = adjacencylist.begin();
(*it).push_back("Some more String");
```

with

```
std::list< vector<string> >::iterator it = adjacencylist.begin();
(*it).push_back("Some more String");
```

Read up on general `constness` [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html) and there is more specific information on `const_iterator` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346890/what-is-the-difference-between-const-iterator-and-iterator).

Answer (score 0):

Use simply an iterator. Also you can use `it -> push_back` instead of `(*it).push_back`.

This is an example:

```
for (list< vector<string> > it = adjacencylist.begin(); it != adjacencylist.end(); ++it)
{
    it -> push_back("Your std::string");
}
```