# Update map which is read-only object using c++

Tags: c++

```
void value_multi(const map<string, double>& myMap, string target,double alva) {

    double res = 0;
    map<string, double>::const_iterator iter = myMap.begin();
    for(; iter!=myMap.end(); ++iter) {
        string key = iter->first;
        vector<string> strs;
        boost::split(strs,key, boost::is_any_of("|"));

        if(strs[0] == target) { //if target == string value
            //res += iter->second;
            double tmp=iter->second*alva; // set tmp
            iter->second=tmp;  //update value
        }
    }

    //return res;
}
```

I want to update a value using method like code ,but it shows some message after compile

```
[Error] assignment of member 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, double>::second' in read-only object
```

Is that any easy and quick way to change my code that will easy update the `iter->second` value

Comment: If you plan to update it, why do you pass it as a `const` parameter?

Comment: I don't mean to be smug, but the question title seems to be an oxymoron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "normal" `iterator` instead of a `const_iterator`, since the later is read only:

```
map<string, double>::iterator iter = myMap.begin();
```

See:
[what is the difference between const_iterator and iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346890/what-is-the-difference-between-const-iterator-and-iterator)

**Note** that you also will have to change the parameter type `const map<string, double>& myMap` of your function to a non const type:

```
void value_multi(map<string, double>& myMap, string target,double alva)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator is const:

```
map<string, double>::const_iterator iter
```

so you cannot assign / change its contents. Make it non const to do it:

```
map<string, double>::iterator iter
```

but then you will also have to make myMap non const

Answer (score 2):

Use const cast

```
const_cast<double&>(iter->second) = tmp;
```

It changed the constness of a variable. Because it's not a good practice to modify a const object, I recommend to change the const modifiers in the map argument like this.

```
void value_multi(map<string, double>& myMap, string target,double alva) {

    double res = 0;
    map<string, double>::iterator iter = myMap.begin();
    for(; iter!=myMap.end(); ++iter) {
        string key = iter->first;
        vector<string> strs;
        boost::split(strs,key, boost::is_any_of("|"));

        if(strs[0] == target) { //if target == string value
            //res += iter->second;
            double tmp=iter->second*alva; // set tmp
            iter->second=tmp;  //update value
        }
    }

    //return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've passed the `map` by const reference--that's a promise that you **won't** modify the `map`. In this case, however, your whole intent *is* to modify the map.

The cure is simple: pass the map by non-`const` reference (which would allow a non-const iterator, but see below: the code you have using the iterator should also be eliminated).

The rest of your code is unnecessarily inefficient. Right now, you're walking through every element of the map. At each iteration, you split the `target` string, and check whether the current map element is equal to the first part of the `target` string.

I'd write the code more like:

```
std::string key = target.substr(0, target.find("|"));

auto pos = myMap.find(key);
if (pos != myMap.end())
    pos->second *= alva;
```