# C++ iterator for vector of struct Compiler Error Ask

Tags: c++, stdvector

why this code works with the function argument?

```
void GameBoard::showField(std::vector<int> newBoard) const {
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = newBoard.begin(); it < newBoard.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

with class property not work

```
void GameBoard::showField() const {
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = this->board.begin(); it < this->board.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `this->board` is `const` in the function, so you need a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Define what you mean by "_works_", and "_doesn't work_" I suspect that the code doesn't compile due to you needing to use `const_iterator`.

Comment: Is the compiler error a secret? A mystery? Where is your [MCVE]?

Comment: @mch Answers go in the answer section please and thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the difference between const\_iterator and iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346890/what-is-the-difference-between-const-iterator-and-iterator)

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your function argument is a `std::vector<int>`. As such, `.begin()` gives you a nice `std::vector<int>::iterator`. This matches the usage in your loop.

However, your member, when accessed via a `const` member function like `showField`, is also `const`. It is now a `const std::vector<int>` in that context. As such, `.begin()` gives you a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` instead.

You wrote out `std::vector<int>::iterator` explicitly though and the two don't match.

You don't modify the values so just stick with `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` or, y'know, `auto`.

I mean, really what you want is this:

```
void GameBoard::showField() const
{
   for (const auto& el : board)
      std::cout << ' ' << el;

   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Ideally take the stream as an argument too:

```
std::ostream& GameBoard::showField(std::ostream& os) const
{
   for (const auto& el : board)
      os << ' ' << el;

   os << '\n';
   return os;
}
```

Now we're talking.