# Issue with iterator in a member function

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

```
#ifndef User_hpp
#define User_hpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Account.hpp"
#include "Associazione.hpp"
#include <vector>

class User : public Account{

private:
    string date;
    string surname;
    string address;
    vector<Associazione> links;

public:
    void iterateVector() const;
...
```

Now, if i want to iterate "links" vector.. i've developed method "iterateVector()" into .cpp file like that:

```
#include "User.hpp"
#include <iostream>

User::User(){

}

void User::iterateVector() const{
for (vector<Associazione>::iterator it = links.begin(); it != 
     links.end(); ++it){
}
```

but compiler returns me an error:

> No viable conversion from '__wrap_iter std::__1::vector Associazione, std::__1::allocator Associazione ::const_pointer' to '__wrap_iter

Can someone help me?..

Comment: Sounds like you need `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: I've never use it.. what's that? whats change?..

Comment: As @πάντα said, use `vector<Associazione>::const_iterator`. Also see [What is the difference between const_iterator and iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346890/608639) and [What is the difference between const_iterator and non-const iterator in the C++ STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309581/608639)

Comment: Or even better: `for(auto link : links) { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
void User::iterateVector() const{
for (vector<Associazione>::iterator it = links.begin(); it != 
     links.end(); ++it){
}
```

should be

```
void User::iterateVector() const{
for (vector<Associazione>::const_iterator it = links.begin(); it != 
     links.end(); ++it){
}
```

because User::iterateVector() is const member function promising not to change any members.

Comment: Can i contact u in private? i have a question :(

Comment: Vittorio: yes okay

Comment: How can i contact u?

Comment: Try sjhowe 777 ATSYMBOL gmail DOTSYMBOL com with the obvious replacements of ATSYMBOL and DOTSYMBOL and take out space characters