# How do you loop through a vector and call a common override function?

Tags: c++, loops, inheritance

I have a vector of  that contains objects that have have inherited the pet class (cat,dog,fish etc). They all have a common override function called play() and I want to call that function with the iterators.

I'm getting bunch of errors. I'm not sure if I am creating my for iterators correctly.

code snippet:

```
void play_pets_x_Times (const std::vector<Pet*>& t, const int16_t x) {

int i=0;
while (i < x) {
   for(std::vector<Pet*>::iterator it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); ++it) {
//error conversion from std::vector<Pet*>....
    it->play();  //error request for member 'play' in....
 }

    i++;
}
}
```

Comment: That should be `const_iterator it`.  Better still, just use `for (auto it = t.begin()` and don't fret about the type.

Comment: Better still, use `for(auto& p : t)` and don't fret about the iterator. And fyi, your original code should have used `(*it)->play()`. The first deref is to acquire the object reference (where the object is `Pet*`, the second via `->` is to deref the ensuing pointer to reach the member function.

Comment: Thank you! Using auto it = ... fixed the first error. And (*it)->play() fixed my second error.

Comment: `for (const auto& element : t) { element->play(); }`

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are pointer-like objects.

On the other hand, you're storing a pointer in the object, not an actual object.

So, to make a long story short, you have 2 things to dereference, but only dereference 1.

```
// (*it) dereferences the iterator to get a Pet*, -> dereferences the Pet*
(*it)->play();
```

That should do the trick.

---

Nope, I'm wrong. You need a `const_iterator` instead [to be const-correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346927/10957435):

```
std::vector<Pet*>::const_iterator it = t.begin();
```

Comment: That won't 'do the trick' without changing the iterator type to `const_iterator` or better still, eliminating it outright.

Comment: It isn't necessary to eliminate it outright to "do the trick", though I agree probably better in the long run. Fixed the `const_iterator` issue.

Comment: you could use `auto it = t.cbegin()`